# Customize google map embed from map maker

Tags: jquery, css, google-maps, google-maps-embed

At the bottom of this page, http://bonner.gydev.com/, we're doing a basic map embed from google map maker.  These lines were all drawn in by someone else and provided in a google earth kmz file, which we were able to import into map maker.  The embed is working fine, but I need to get rid of all the overlays and ONLY show the map with lines and maybe zoom icons.  No top/title bar, no option to show/hide things from the left menu, etc.  Is this possible with a map maker embed?  Tried a jquery approach like below, but no luck.

```
$('iframe').contents().find('.qAWA2').remove();
```

If not possible, I'm not sure how I could get those line coordinates into a more advanced API setup?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks, Rich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easy to do that with the Google Maps JavaScript API. Create a map in your page using the API, and load your KML file as shown in [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml).

If you were so motivated, you could then add other useful features. For example after reading the text and seeing the map I want to know: Where's the go-kart track? Where's the stable? Where's the *house*? You could have a list of features on the side of the satellite map, or even better, make the appropriate words in the main body text clickable, e.g. when you read about taking a fresh mount from the stable, you can click "stable" and zoom in or show a marker on that spot in the map.

[45 degree view](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/aerial-simple) would also be really nice, and easy to add once you're using a Maps API map.

BTW, be wary of using element classes or IDs like the `qAWA2` you probably found in the DOM inspector. Even if you did get this to work, it would probably break in the next few weeks. If a name like `qAWA2` looks like gibberish and not like something any sensible programmer would use, there's a reason for it. The Maps API JavaScript code is run through a minifier before it's released, and that changes private names (functions, classes, etc.) to arbitrary shorter codes. So each time they release a new build and run it through the minifier, these names may change on you.

Or it's possible that `qAWA2` actually is a name they use in the original Maps API source code (maybe the letters stand for something) - but the same principle still applies: it's not documented, so Google may change it at any time.